# specify Gnome Display Manager (GDM) to show the login on a specific monitor with nvidia card

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gnome, gdm, wayland

I'm using Gentoo Linux and I have Nvidia GTX3060 video card and i connect 3 monitors to it, to with DP and one with HDMI.

My desktop is gnome under wayland with Gnome Display Manager (gdm)

now the problem is that gdm is showing the login page on a specific monitor that I sometimes watch tv on, i want to move the login page to show on a different monitor but nothing.. really nothing works!

xrandr --query shows:

```
DP-2 connected 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 340mm
HDMI-2 connected primary 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
DP-1 connected 3840x2160+5120+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
```

I want to login page not to be shown on DP-1, that's all!

so I tried this:

1. in gnome, configured to disable the monitor, and copied the monitors.xml to /var/lib/gdm/.config/monitors.xml (checked permissions and everything) but it didn't change anything.

this is my monitors.xml:

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-2</connector>
          <vendor>GSM</vendor>
          <product>34GL750</product>
          <serial>0x0000c474</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>144.001</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>2560</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-2</connector>
          <vendor>SAM</vendor>
          <product>S27H85x</product>
          <serial>H4ZM300189</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1440</height>
          <rate>59.951</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <disabled>
      <monitorspec>
        <connector>DP-1</connector>
        <vendor>GSM</vendor>
        <product>LG HDR 4K</product>
        <serial>0x00047985</serial>
      </monitorspec>
    </disabled>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

as you can see here DP-1 is disabled. but it changed nothing in gdm.

I also tried to edit `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` and add `xrandr --output DP-1 --off` and it didn't work, i guess it makes sense because I use wayland.

I tried to connect the monitor though DP, or HDMI to any of the other slots in my graphics card and it always loves to show the login on that screen!

I have debug enabled in gdm but i didn't see any error or even indication about monitors.xml there.

any ideas ?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.